# Every thing turned green in fallout 4

Tags: fallout-4

I was in the castle mission, and while travelling to the castle,something went off and the game got stuck for a second. Then everything turned green like in the image below.

Why did this happen? How can I fix it?

[image: everything turned green]

Comment: Maybe...you mutated? Either way, looks cool. No idea tho how it happened.

Comment: Looks like poison effect. Maybe the game glitched and you're stuck with it. Try sleeping or reload a save.

Comment: Were you using a night vision scope? There's been a bug reported when using them, where the screen can be locked in a green tint. I haven't seen a fix for this other than using console commands or loading an earlier save.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault i think i ate something before it happend and i tried sleeping and tried addictol as well but didn't work

Comment: @king14nyr give me the console command and i cant Load and earlier save coz last save takes me back to lvl 19 and my current lvl is 27

Comment: @NoCanDo it looked cool at first but now it is irritating

Comment: rimod 00094636. Let me know how that goes... if it works I can add it as an answer for future users that might run into the same problem.

Comment: @PaulO. nice find, I thought I had seen a question about this bug before, but couldn't find it. The sides of the image on this question are blurred in the same way. I don't know if it'd help to add the part of the 'green tinted view' in the title of that other question.